# Why is app.Run() middleware overriding a specific route mapping in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

1. I have created a middleware using app.Map() that handles a specific route (/hello).
2. However, when I add a second middleware using app.Run() that does not check for a specific route.
3. It seems to overwrite the response of the first middleware even when a request is made to the /hello route.

I'm confused about why this is happening and how to fix it.

The code is below:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using System.Web;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var app = builder.Build();

app.Map("/hello", async (HttpContext context) => {

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
});

app.Run(async (HttpContext context) => {

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bye");

});

app.Run();
```

I tried removing the app.Run() middleware then the specified '/hello' middleware is executing.
But as soon as I add the app.Run() middleware again it then skips the middleware that is mapped to '/hello';

Answer (score 2):

Try switching to `Use`:

```
app.Use(async (HttpContext context, Func<Task> next) =>
{
    await next();

    if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

        await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bye");
    }
});
app.Map("/hello", async (HttpContext context) => {
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
});

app.Run();
```

I guess that the behaviour is due to the fact that the [`RunExtensions.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.runextensions.run?view=aspnetcore-7.0) adds something called "terminal middleware delegate".

Also [ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0) article can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

You could check the [source codes](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Http.Abstractions/src/Extensions/RunExtensions.cs) of `RunExtensions.Run()` method here

```
public static class RunExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Adds a terminal middleware delegate to the application's request pipeline.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="app">The <see cref="IApplicationBuilder"/> instance.</param>
    /// <param name="handler">A delegate that handles the request.</param>
    public static void Run(this IApplicationBuilder app, RequestDelegate handler)
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(app);
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(handler);

        app.Use(_ => handler);
    }
}
```

it adds a middleware like

```
app.Use(next => async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bye");

});
```

if you don't branch the pipeline ,your request would be shortcut

You could try with Guru Stron's solution or

```
app.MapFallback(async (HttpContext context) =>
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Bye");
});
```

Or branch the pipeline:

```
app.Map("/hello",app=>app.Run(async (HttpContext context) =>
{

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";

    await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello");
}));
```

For your requirement

You could check the difference:
[image]
[image]